# CSS: Style checkbox labels only

Tags: css

Is there any way that i can select on css the labels that are for checkboxes only?

I am using this css code 
    input[type="radio"], 
    input[type="checkbox"] 
    { 
        position: absolute; left: -999em; 
    }

```
label:before 
{ 
    display: inline-block; position: relative; top:0.25em; left:-2px; 
    content:''; width:25px; height:25px;
    background-image:url(formelements.png); 
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before 
{ 
    background-position: 0 -25px;
}         
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before 
{
    background-position: 0 0 ; 
}
input[type="radio"] + label:before 
{ 
    background-position: -25px -25px;
} 
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before 
{
    background-position: -25px 0;
}
```

If you want the image you can get it from [here](http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/pure-css-custom-form-elements/formelements.png) and also the guide i am following for the styling can be found [here](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/10/26/custom-style-all-your-form-elements-with-pure-css-and-no-javascript/)
But the problem i am facing is that all my labels for all the inputs get affected. Is there a way to style only those labels that are for checkboxes?

Thanks in regards

Comment: On first glance nothing seems wrong? Can you provide a link or create a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css

Comment: The problem as i can see it is with the label:before . All my labels are getting changed, even the ones that i have for input of type text,password,tel etc.

Answer (score 0):

Custom CSS for checkbox labels. Works in my case:

```
.medview input[type="checkbox"][class="selectorThumbs"] + label:before {
    background: url('../icons/thumbs.png') no-repeat;
}
.medview input[type="checkbox"][class="selectorThumbs"]:checked + label:before {
    background: url('../icons/thumbs1.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Why not use the normal dot notation?